# How to get a batch of file version using a SVN repository

Tags: svn, version-control, build-script

I have a build process that copies files out of the repository to make a binary image. I need the file revisions for all of the files in the repository for the build process.  I know that I can run `svn info [filename]` and get the file version that way but I have over 4k files I need version info for.

Is there a way to get these version numbers *en masse* or do I need to write a svn hook that maintains an XML file or something with the latest version numbers?

EDIT: The output I am looking for would be that for revision 4329 for the folder the list of files revisions are: file1.txt = revision 3; file2.txt = revision 9; ... We need to have this list so when we update the firmware on our devices we only copy the changes they absolutely need. So they can skip two or three firmware revisions, but because the device knows it has revision 3 of file1.txt we don't need to update that file in the firmware vs file2.txt which has revision 7 on the device and would need to be updated to revision 9.

Hope that helps make it more clear than before.

Comment: I want the version NUMBER, not the version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question - do you want to get a load of files from SVN for a given revnum (remembering that each commit increments a global revnum, not increments a revnum for each file) then you just need to specify the revision.

so if you checkout revision x, you get a snapshot of all the files at that point. There's no need to determine the revnum for the last time each individual file was changed.

Comment: I need the revision number for each file. We use this information later, but I need to figure out how to get the revision number for each file on a project with over 4k files hopefully in a relativity brief (less than 30 min's) time frame.

Comment: no such thing as revision number for each file. SVN uses a 'snapshot' system where each rev number is a brand new view of the entire repo. this is a good thing as 1 rev number can then show you every file at a particular point in time - no need to branch or keep a list of file revnumbers.  Its not like CVS. So getting revision 4329 gets you the correct file version for *every file*.

Comment: Whether SVN assigns a different version to files than to the check-in is irrelevant.  If I open a project click on one of the files (`test1.c`) and use TortoiseSVN to "Show Log" then I can see the revision for this file is `54409`. I then open a different file (`test2.c`) and the revision is `54113` and the repository version is `55454` and that every file that participates in that revision gets that same number. So long as I know that the last time `test1.c` was last checked in with revision `54409` that is the number I am after for every file in the repository.

Comment: try to understand what happens. Sure, you look at a file at it says changed as revs 100 and 110. So what version of the file do you get if you checkout revision 105? Answer that question and everything should become clear.